# generate Podfile.lock without a Mac

Tags: xcode, react-native, podfile-lock

I need to generate a new Podfile.lock for a React Native project for iOS, but I don't own a mac. Is there a way to do it online ? I'm trying to deploy the project for iOS through CodeMagic, but the error returned by CodeMagic makes me believe I need to update the Podfile.lock.

The error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.6.0)

  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 12.9.3, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.8.0)


You have either:
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `RNFBApp`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v13.1.1 but found v12.9.3, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v13.1.1 but found v12.9.3, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any online tool to generate a podfile.lock. That's kind of the purpose of using a tool of CodeMagic - to run your code on a Mac to build.

Have you tried just deleting your podfile.lock? A new one should get generated during the build process.

Comment: Thanks, mate. It worked :)

Comment: Is there a way to download the generated Podfile.lock from CodeMagic ?

Comment: I'm not certain but I would imagine not. I'm not sure why you would want or need it locally if you're not running your app on a Mac locally. If you were giving the code to someone else then they would be able to generate one with a `pod install` as and when.